# Horizontally scrollable menu with dropdown overflow-y visible not wokring

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox, overflow, dropdown

I made a horizontally scrollable menu and now I want to add dropdown. However the overflow seems to get clipped even though I set it to `overflow-y:visible`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.card-block {
    min-height: 300px;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="padding-left:1%;height:150px;width:60%; background-color:red; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:visible;">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
        
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
        <span class="border">
            <a>wtest1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span><span class="border">
            <a>test1</a>
        </span>
        <span class="border">
            <a>test2</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```